# Modifying DOM element attributes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, html, video, html5-video

How can I modify the `poster` attribute of a video element with JavaScript?

```
<video id="vid" poster="AB.png">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is:

```
document.getElementById("vid").setAttribute("poster","newValue");
```

With jQuery that would be:

```
jQuery("#vid").attr("poster","newValue");
```

And it is also a DOM property/id attribute:

```
document.getElementById("vid").poster = "newValue";
```

With jQuery that would be:

```
jQuery("#vid").prop("poster","newValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, poster is an attribute like any other.

In straight JS

```
document.getElementById("vid").setAttribute("poster","foo");
```

With jQuery

```
$('#vid').attr('poster','foo');
```